# how to call services from another controller

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

hello i am integrating paypal in ionic app using this link

https://ionicandroidlearning.blogspot.com/2015/11/ionic-paypal-integration.html?showComment=1479300394529#c5798386064000573129

when i click on button to start paypal payment i have getting that error.
i have add all files in js folder and also add their reference in index.html

```
ionic.bundle.js:26799 ReferenceError: PaypalService is not defined
    at ChildScope.$scope.click (app.js:36)
    at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:27643), <anonymous>:4:206)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65429
    at ChildScope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at ChildScope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30500)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:65428)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (ionic.bundle.js:16792)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:16780)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2953)
    at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2942)
```

my index.html file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/paypal-mobile-js-helper.js"></script>

    <script src="js/cdv-plugin-paypal-mobile-sdk.js"></script>
    <script src="js/payPalService.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      <button ng-click="click()"> payment</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js file

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
//.service('myService', function () { /* ... */ })

.controller('MyCtrl' , function($scope){



  $scope.click=function()
  {
console.log("i am call");

 // console.log(error);
PaypalService.initPaymentUI().then(function () {

PaypalService.makePayment(90, "Total Amount").then(function (response) {

alert("success"+JSON.stringify(response));

}, function (error) {

alert('Transaction Canceled');

});

}); 

  };



})


.constant('shopSettings',{

payPalSandboxId :'Aar8HZzvc5NztVWodTBpOiOod9wWrBDrJUjyvRr4WsxcCD28xYig7oecfYsqxQUDu5QHptPpSALirxZD',

payPalProductionId : 'production id here',

payPalEnv: 'PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', // for testing production for production

payPalShopName : 'MyShopName',

payPalMerchantPrivacyPolicyURL : 'url to policy',

payPalMerchantUserAgreementURL : ' url to user agreement'

})
```

paypalServices.js

```
    var app=angular.module('starter.payPalService', [])


    app.factory('PaypalService', ['$q', '$ionicPlatform', 'shopSettings', '$filter', '$timeout', function ($q, $ionicPlatform, shopSettings, $filter, $timeout) {
    var init_defer;
    /**
    * Service object
    * @type object
    */
    var service = {
    initPaymentUI: initPaymentUI,
    createPayment: createPayment,
    configuration: configuration,
    onPayPalMobileInit: onPayPalMobileInit,
    makePayment: makePayment
    };
    /**
    * @ngdoc method
    * @name initPaymentUI
    * @methodOf app.PaypalService
    * @description
    * Inits the payapl ui with certain envs.
    *
    *
    * @returns {object} Promise paypal ui init done
    */
    function initPaymentUI() {
    init_defer = $q.defer();
    $ionicPlatform.ready().then(function () {
    var clientIDs = {
    "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": shopSettings.payPalProductionId,
    "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": shopSettings.payPalSandboxId
    };
    PayPalMobile.init(clientIDs, onPayPalMobileInit);
    });
    return init_defer.promise;
    }
    /**
    * @ngdoc method
    * @name createPayment
    * @methodOf app.PaypalService
    * @param {string|number} total total sum. Pattern 12.23
    * @param {string} name name of the item in paypal
    * @description
    * Creates a paypal payment object
    *
    *
    * @returns {object} PayPalPaymentObject
    */
    function createPayment(total, name) {
    // "Sale == > immediate payment
    // "Auth" for payment authorization only, to be captured separately at a later time.
    // "Order" for taking an order, with authorization and capture to be done separately at a later time.
    var payment = new PayPalPayment("" + total, "EUR", "" + name, "Sale");
    return payment;
    }
    /**
    * @ngdoc method
    * @name configuration
    * @methodOf app.PaypalService
    * @description
    * Helper to create a paypal configuration object
    *
    *
    * @returns {object} PayPal configuration
    */
    function configuration() {
    // for more options see `paypal-mobile-js-helper.js`
    var config = new PayPalConfiguration({merchantName: shopSettings.payPalShopName, merchantPrivacyPolicyURL: shopSettings.payPalMerchantPrivacyPolicyURL, merchantUserAgreementURL: shopSettings.payPalMerchantUserAgreementURL});
    return config;
    }
    function onPayPalMobileInit() {
    $ionicPlatform.ready().then(function () {
    // must be called
    // use PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork mode to get look and feel of the flow
    PayPalMobile.prepareToRender(shopSettings.payPalEnv, configuration(), function () {
    $timeout(function () {
    init_defer.resolve();
    });
    });
    });
    }
    /**
    * @ngdoc method
    * @name makePayment
    * @methodOf app.PaypalService
    * @param {string|number} total total sum. Pattern 12.23
    * @param {string} name name of the item in paypal
    * @description
    * Performs a paypal single payment
    *
    *
    * @returns {object} Promise gets resolved on successful payment, rejected on error
    */
    function makePayment(total, name) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    total = $filter('number')(total, 2);
    $ionicPlatform.ready().then(function () {
    PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI(createPayment(total, name), function (result) {
    $timeout(function () {
    defer.resolve(result);
    });
    }, function (error) {
    $timeout(function () {
    defer.reject(error);
    });
    });
    });
    return defer.promise;
    }
    return service;
    }]);
```

Comment: you need to mention your service in your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are declaring `starter.payPalService` as separate module, You need to inject it to the parent module,

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','starter.payPalService'])
```

And in controller, make sure you inject the service,

```
.controller('MyCtrl' , function($scope,PaypalService){
}
```

Comment: thanks its work now i have call service successfully.